# Redirecionar por faixa de ip javascript

Tags: javascript

é possível redirecionar para algum site pela faixa de ip. Para um unico ip foi ok.
Segue meu codigo;

```
<html>
    <head>
    
    <script type="application/javascript">
    function verIP(json) 
    {
        if (json.ip == "11.222.111.11")
        {
            window.location = "https://www.google.com";
        }
        else if (json.ip == "00.111.222.33")
        {
            window.location = "https://www.uol.com.br";
        }
        else
        {
            window.location = "https://www.terra.com.br";
        }   
    }
    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=verIP"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <h1>Teste redirecionar</h1>
    <h2>teste</h2>
    
</html>
```